# undefined reference to `_GetAdaptersAddresses@20' - but I included -liphlpapi

Tags: c++, c, winapi, gcc, cygwin

I'm using `gcc` under `cygwin` to write some code that calls `GetAdaptersAddresses` from `iphlpapi.h` in my code I've set `_WIN32_WINNT` above the required `0x0501` and on the linker line I've added `-liphlpapi` but the linker is still failing with the following message:

```
gcc -liphlpapi build/obj/*.o -Wall -Wextra -o build/bin/asdf.exe src/asdf.cpp
/tmp/ccdjLPVY.o:asdf.cpp:(.text+0x153): undefined reference to `_GetAdaptersAddresses@20'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Some snippets from `asdf.cpp`:

```
#if _WIN32_WINNT < 0x0501
  #warning _WIN32_WINNT was set lower than 0x0501, fixing
  #undef _WIN32_WINNT
  #define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#endif
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
```

I know they're there darn it:

```
strings /usr/i686-pc-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libiphlpapi.a  | sort | uniq | grep GetAdapters
__imp__GetAdaptersAddresses@20
__imp__GetAdaptersInfo@8
_GetAdaptersAddresses@20
_GetAdaptersInfo@8
GetAdaptersAddresses
GetAdaptersInfo

$strings /usr/lib/w32api/libiphlpapi.a  | sort | uniq | grep GetAdapters
__imp__GetAdaptersAddresses@20
__imp__GetAdaptersInfo@8
_GetAdaptersAddresses@20
_GetAdaptersInfo@8
GetAdaptersAddresses
GetAdaptersInfo
```

Is anyone seeing what I've missed?

### Edit: Answer

```
# Change the order, put the linker options last:
# Before:
gcc -liphlpapi build/obj/*.o -Wall -Wextra -o build/bin/asdf.exe src/asdf.cpp
# After:
gcc            build/obj/*.o -Wall -Wextra -o build/bin/asdf.exe src/asdf.cpp -liphlpapi
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970356/undefined-reference-to-mysql-init)  talks about how the order matters. Does that help?

Comment: @chris That did the trick, please submit an answer with that link

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10970356/undefined-reference-to-mysql-init), the order of gcc arguments matters. You need to move the library inclusion to after the objects that depend on it.

So `gcc build/obj/*.o -liphlpapi ...`

Answer (score 2):

try adding #pragma comment(lib, "Iphlpapi.lib")

Comment: This doesn't work on GCC. I remember trying it extensively when my settings kept resetting due to a technicality of it being on a flash drive.

Comment: @chris because the `#pragma` is sets exclusively a compiler defined directives.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, Yes, it is. My point was that the OP obviously uses GCC and this answer only works on MSVC.